# Stored procedure call from java throwing 'Cursor state not valid' error

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, iseries-navigator

I am getting a 'Cursor state not valid' error when I try to run the stored procedure.
The 13th parameter acts as a both IN/ OUT which returns value on both cases but it requires parameter value when its an update. This stored proc works when I try to run in IBM iSerires but fails through java.
Not sure what I am missing here. Thanks in advance.

```
public String saveContact(Contact payload, Context cntx, String contactType) {

    Connection connection = null;
    String headerKey = null;
    try {
        connection = ds.getConnection();
        CallableStatement callable = invokeStoredProc(connection, payload, contactType);

        ResultSet rs = callable.executeQuery();  //ERRORS OUT HERE
        while (rs.next()) {
            headerKey = rs.getString(13);
        }
        String output = callable.getString(14);
        if(!_helper.containsValue(output)){
            logger.error("WISE Stored proc execution results an errorCode: " + output.trim());
        }


        callable.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        logger.error("Exception here. {}", e.getMessage());

    } finally {
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("closing database connection: {} ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return headerKey;
}



public CallableStatement invokeStoredProc(Connection connection, Contact payload, String contactType) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Calling WISE stored proc through invokeWISECustomerContactStoredProc()");


    CallableStatement call = connection.prepareCall("{CALL CONTACT_SP(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}");
    if(Constants.CONTACT_PROCESS_UPDATE.equalsIgnoreCase(contactType)){
        logger.info("Contact already exists. Set to update it");

        call.setString(1, "UPDATE");
        call.registerOutParameter(13, Types.CHAR);
        call.setString(13, "345");

    }else{

        logger.info("Set to save the new contact.");
        call.setString(1, "ADD");
        call.registerOutParameter(13, Types.CHAR);
        call.setString(13, "");

    }
    call.setString(1, "ADD");
    call.setString(2, "00345");
    call.setString(3, "000245");
    call.setString(4, "Mr");
    call.setString(5, "Mark");
    call.setString(6, "T");
    call.setString(7, "Taylor");
    call.setString(8, "taylor@yahoo.com");
    call.setString(9, "9375551456");
    call.setString(10, "9375551789");
    call.setString(11, "9375551345");
    call.setString(12, "MarkT02");
    call.setString(14, "");
    call.registerOutParameter(14, Types.CHAR);
    return call;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling "callable.execute()" instead?

Comment: It worked on callable.executeUpdate() . thanks